# I need an error handler for my command, otherwise i just get many errors

Tags: discord.py

```py
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
#some embed stuff in here
await ctx.message.delete()
 await ctx.send('Heyy, check your DM`s!', delete_after=10)
 await ctx.author.send(embed=em)
```

this should about show you what i have until now. I need an error handler because ofcourse my bot cannot delete messages in dms. so if a user does !help in dms I either want it to say ,you cannot execute this command in dms, or just the same embed from the normal commmand

Comment: Why would you want to ignore the errors? Isn't it just easier to handle them with a try/except block? Ignoring and suppressing errors is a bad, bad idea. Also -- StackOverflow is **not** a "code it for me" type of site, you have to make an honest approach to solve the problem and ask a specific *programming* question, take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: the thing is, i dont want to ignore the errors, i need an error handler for it, but i dont how to do that, thats why i asked the question. please read carefully before you write something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`@commands.guild_only()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=guild_only#discord.ext.commands.guild_only) which produces the error `NoPrivateMessage` error

```py
@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def help(ctx):
    #some embed stuff in here
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send('Heyy, check your DM`s!', delete_after=10)
    await ctx.author.send(embed=em
```

or

```py
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    if ctx.guild is None: return await ctx.send("I can only be ran in a server!")
    #some embed stuff in here
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send('Heyy, check your DM`s!', delete_after=10)
    await ctx.author.send(embed=em
```